# How to save a trained Neural Network with TensorFlow2

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, save

My problem is that after creating and training a neural net with TensorFlow (version 2.1.0) I need to extrapolate all the basic parameters: net architecture, functions used and weight values found through training.

These parameters will then be read by a library that will generate the VHDL code to bring the neural network created on python on an FPGA.

So I wanted to ask if there are one or more methods to get all this information, not in binary format. Among all these values the most important one is the extrapolation of the value of the weights found at the end of the training.

Comment: It's hard to help with no minimal example to work with, and with no details about what exactly you expect. You can save Keras models in different ways, or you can export a `tf.function` into a GraphDef, although I think the "variable freezing" part is not so straightforward in TF 2.x. You could [convert your model to ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx), which may be more compatible with the FPGA tooling anyway.

Comment: Now I'll see how to perform my model in ONNX. I scyuso if I did not provide the code, my question referred to the phase after the creation and training of a model, for example:

`model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)`.

At this point, I would like to have a function that summarizes the neural network I created, including the values of the weights.